# Push notification is firing success event but not received on device

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap, pushsharp

I am using phonegap.
The push notification is sent to the iOS device while debugging the success event is always fired but the notification is not always received. I am using the latest pushsharp version.

Thank you.